# Suddenly disconnects while playing using "Google Play Game Services"

Tags: android, google-play-games

I followed Google guide (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer) and implemented multiplayer in my game. Everything seems to be working ok, but "sometimes" connection is lost suddenly, and no event is executed (onLeftRoom nor onDisconnectedFromRoom) after it happens...

If I see the logcat, I can see some relevant information:

```
09-19 15:50:08.623: I/libjingle(10434): void buzz::PresencePushTask::HandlePresence(const buzz::Jid&, const buzz::XmlElement*): Received directed presence :0x4dxicadq3fv30u0iy8gcj9yz@public.talk.google.com/games_andr34DE8388
09-19 15:50:08.623: E/DataConnectionManager(10434): Received directed presence of type 'unavailable' from peer.
09-19 15:50:08.623: I/libjingle(10434): Removing from roster: 0x4dxicadq3fv30u0iy8gcj9yz@public.talk.google.com/games_andr34DE8388
09-19 15:50:08.683: W/libjingle(10434): Warning(libjingleclient.cpp:1183): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::TerminateAllCalls_w(): Terminating call for session:1464668934
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/DataConnectionManager(10434): onConnectionResult called for sessionId: 1464668934 result: false
09-19 15:50:08.693: D/rtmp:LibjingleEventHandler(10434): [libjingleHandler] handleMessage(CALL_STATE_CHANGED): for sessionId: 1464668934 new state=12
09-19 15:50:08.693: W/libjingle(10434): Warning(callregistry.cpp:27): void games_rtmp::CallRegistry::UnregisterCall(const string&, const string&): Attempting to erase non-existent session:1464668934
09-19 15:50:08.693: E/DataConnectionManager(10434): tearDown() called when network is NOT ready for match !
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): worker_thread:0x62acd7d8 initialized=1
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): Waiting for a reply.
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): Channel disabled
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): Destroyed channel
09-19 15:50:08.693: I/libjingle(10434): Waiting for a reply.
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/DataConnectionManager(10434): onConnectionResult called for sessionId: 1464668934 result: false
09-19 15:50:08.703: E/DataConnectionManager(10434): Could not find JID for session ID 1464668934
09-19 15:50:08.703: D/rtmp:LibjingleEventHandler(10434): [libjingleHandler] handleMessage(CALL_STATE_CHANGED): for sessionId: 1464668934 new state=15
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/libjingle(10434): Waiting for a reply.
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/libjingle(10434): Waiting for a reply.
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/libjingle(10434): worker_thread:0x62acd7d8 initialized=1
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/libjingle(10434): Waiting for a reply.
09-19 15:50:08.703: I/libjingle(10434): SSL Cleanup
```

I'm getting crazy with this... anybody can help me please?

Comment: I see similar messages in my game. I use latest. gpg v 1.4.1 and get this: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I'm testing a code that worked two days ago so I think that it is caused by google. Try it later.

Comment: The error it is still showing up and I have try everything. I just sent a mesage to the Google support team...

Comment: Any news? Do you know where to know more about it?

Answer (score 2):

I have update googleplayservice-lib and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening more frequently past few days even on wifi. I guess your code is fine and it is Google related issue that will sort itself out.